# React conditional divs with hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am creating a signup form that will render differently depending on whether the person signing up chooses `Post a project` or `Work on a project` from the very first div in the form.

**How can I render each div that follows in the `form-group` conditionally** based on what is selected in the first div? I am using hooks and I have found that most examples are for the `extends Component` approach.

My form:

```
const signUpForm = () => (
  <form onSubmit={clickSubmit}>
    <div className="form-group">
      <select onChange={handleChange("role")} class="form-control">
        <option selected>I want to...</option>
        <option>Post a project</option>
        <option>Work on a project</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div className="form-group">
      <input
        onChange={handleChange("name")}
        type="text"
        placeholder="Name"
        className="form-control"
        value={name}
      />
    </div>

    <div className="form-group">
      <input
        onChange={handleChange("email")}
        type="email"
        placeholder="Email"
        className="form-control"
        value={email}
      />
    </div>

    <div className="form-group">
      <input
        onChange={handleChange("password")}
        type="password"
        placeholder="Password"
        className="form-control"
        value={password}
      />
    </div>

    <div className="form-group">
      <input
        onChange={handleChange("studying")}
        type="text"
        placeholder="I'm studying..."
        className="form-control"
        value={studying}
      />
    </div>

    <div>
      <div>{createInputs()}</div>
      <button
        className="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm mb-3"
        onClick={addSkill}
        type="text"
      >
        Add more skills
      </button>
    </div>

    <button onClick={clickSubmit} className="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
      Sign Up
    </button>
  </form>
);
```

**State:**

```
const Signup = () => {
  const [values, setValues] = useState({
    name: "",
    email: "",
    password: "",
    studying: "",
    skills: [""],
    error: "",
    success: "",
    role: ""
  });

  const { name, email, password, studying, skills, success, error, role } = values;
```

**handleChange():**

```
 const handleChange = name => event => {
    setValues({ ...values, error: false, [name]: event.target.value });
  };
```

Comment: I do not get what you want to do, Do you have a state to save the form answer?

Comment: No, is that the way to accomplish this? I want all components after the first select bar div to render conditionally based on that selection

Comment: Which components should be displayed depending on the selection option? If you are looking for a generic answer, you can simply create a state, which is bound to the `select` value and conditionally display the `divs` like `{selectedValue === 'post' && <PostItems />} {selectedValue === 'work' && <WorkItems />}` etc. where `PostItems` and `WorkItems` would be what you might want to wrap or inline if needed

Comment: ok, you can useState to do that. `const [isPost, setIsPost] = useState(false);`
for instance you save the state after choosing witch type the user selected, and render conditionally a div or a component.

Comment: Where are your `value` variables (e.g. `email`, `password`) and `handleChange` defined?

Comment: Added state and handlechange

Comment: @DavideLorino The code is not complete, where is signUpForm being called? Where the section which asks "Post a project" or "Work on project"?

Comment: Please provide some form of expected output/result. It is impossible to answer if it isn't known what you want.

Comment: @Tapas its literally the first div

Comment: @DrewReese There are multiple div tags in this form. I want everything after the first div in the signup form to appear only IF a selection is made from the first div.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should first divide the signUp in two parts and then call second function based on value of "role" from state.

The idea is to return the divs from second function based on state of first input.

```
const signUpForm = () => (
  <form onSubmit={clickSubmit}>
    <div className="form-group">
      <select onChange={handleChange("role")} class="form-control">
        <option selected>I want to...</option>
        <option>Post a project</option>
        <option>Work on a project</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    {this.renderInput()}

    <button onClick={clickSubmit} className="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
      Sign Up
    </button>
  </form>
);

renderInput() {
    if (values.role === "post") {
        return (
            <div className="form-group">
                <input onChange={handleChange("name")} type="text" placeholder="Name" className="form-control" value={name} />
            </div>

            <div className="form-group">
                <input onChange={handleChange("email")} type="email" placeholder="Email" className="form-control" value={email} />
            </div>

            <div className="form-group">
                <input onChange={handleChange("password")} type="password" placeholder="Password" className="form-control" value={password} />
            </div>

            <div className="form-group">
                <input onChange={handleChange("studying")} type="text" placeholder="I'm studying..." className="form-control" value={studying} />
            </div>

            <div>
                <div>{createInputs()}</div>
                <button className="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm mb-3" onClick={addSkill} type="text">
                    Add more skills
                </button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to test the role state value is truthy/falsey and render the rest of your form on that value.

```
const SignUpForm = () => (
  <form onSubmit={clickSubmit}>
    <div className="form-group">
      <select
        defaultValue='unselected' // set default value here
        onChange={handleChange("role")}
        className="form-control" // fix className here, class alone isn't correct in react
      >
        <option value='unselected'>I want to...</option>
        <option value='post'>Post a project</option>
        <option value='work'>Work on a project</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    {!!role && (
      <Fragment>
        <div className="form-group">
          <input
            onChange={handleChange("name")}
            type="text"
            placeholder="Name"
            className="form-control"
            value={name}
          />
        </div>

        <div className="form-group">
          <input
            onChange={handleChange("email")}
            type="email"
            placeholder="Email"
            className="form-control"
            value={email}
          />
        </div>

        <div className="form-group">
          <input
            onChange={handleChange("password")}
            type="password"
            placeholder="Password"
            className="form-control"
            value={password}
          />
        </div>

        <div className="form-group">
          <input
            onChange={handleChange("studying")}
            type="text"
            placeholder="I'm studying..."
            className="form-control"
            value={studying}
          />
        </div>

        <div>
          <div>{createInputs()}</div>
          <button
            className="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm mb-3"
            onClick={addSkill}
            type="text"
          >
            Add more skills
          </button>
        </div>
      </Fragment>
    )}

    <button onClick={clickSubmit} className="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
      Sign Up
    </button>
  </form>
);
```

[image: Edit sharp-lake-ouclt]